# Find Object Inside Array of Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have an array of objects with each containing an array of objects.

My goal is to find a `nested object` in a single line of javascript code. I am trying to avoid a nested loop, I know how to solve it that way but javascript offers a lot of elegant solutions for such scenarios.

**This is how my data looks like:**

```
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Test 1',
        data: [
            {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Test 3',
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                title: 'Test 4',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Test 2',
        data: [
            {
                id: 5,
                title: 'Test 5',
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

**With a nested loop:**

```
let item = null;
for (let i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j<items[i].data; j++) {
        if (items[i].data[j].id == myId) {
            item = items[i].data[j];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like there is a more simplistic and prettier solution than this.

Comment: Are you able to use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: I know how to use it on flat structures but I am unsure about nested structures. Would you mind elaborating? Sorry if this is a silly question, I am not an expert in javascript.

Comment: `const item = items.find((parent) => parent.data.find((child) => child.id === id));`

This is what I tried but it returns the parent with all its children.

Comment: `let item; for (const { data } of items) { if (item = data.find(e => e.id === myID)) break; }`, or write a more general function for it.

Comment: why do you want it in one of code?,  Focus on Optimizing the logic, not lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that in one line. As I saw in your nested loop solution, you find in each object's data, so first you could flatten the data in to array of objects and then find through that array

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Test 1",
    data: [
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Test 3",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: "Test 4",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Test 2",
    data: [
      {
        id: 5,
        title: "Test 5",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const myId = 4;

const res = items.flatMap((item) => item.data).find(({ id }) => id === myId);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Good solution. Just a minor callout, this is not supported in IE. if that's not a problem, then this would be a good option - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, I would suggest the way is to use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combined with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const items = [{id:1,title:"Test 1",data:[{id:3,title:"Test 3",},{id:4,title:"Test 4",},],},{id:2,title:"Test 2",data:[{id:5,title:"Test 5",},],},];

const myId = 4;
const res = items.reduce((acc, {data}) => {
  const foundItem = data.find(({id}) => id === myId);
  if(foundItem)
    acc.push(foundItem);
  
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```